# After Android Studio 4.2.0 update gradle error solved

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjn1t.png)

After i did my 4.2.0 android studio update i got gradle module error.I just solved it so i publish it to whom got the same error.Just change the following path In the picture,on the build.gradle part .On default it writes ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release 764".After you change it to  ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0" ,android studio redownload the module and you good to go.Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool, but if you're posting a Q&A, you should post a clear question with everything needed to understand it, including the error message etc., as text (not an image) - with a separate answer that you then accept.

Comment: Ty for your reply.I'm new so i'm gonna be more specific next time.Have a good day.